# Double-matching in a bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I've encountered the following problem studying for my Algorithm test, with no answer published to it:

1. Maximum double matching problem- given a bipartite graph G=(V=(LUR),E) describe an algorithm that returns a group of edges M in E s.t for each vertex v in V there are at most 2 edges in M that include v, of a maximum size.
2. Definition: a "Strong double matching" is a double matching s.t for each vertice v in V there is at least one edge in M that includes v. Given a bipartite graph G=(V=(LUR),E) and strong double matching M, describe an algorithm that returns a strong double matching M' of maximum size. Prove your answer.

so I've already managed to solve

1) using reduction to max-flow: adding vertices's s and t and edges from s to L and edges from R to t each with the capacity of 2, and defining the capacity of each edge between L and R with the infinite capacity. Finding a max flow using Dinic's algorithm and returning all edges with positive flow between L and R.

about 2) i thought about somehow manipulating the network so that there is positive flow from each vertex then using the algorithm from a somehow to construct a maximum solution. Any thoughts? The runtime restriction is O(V^2E) (Dinics runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in O(n^3) using [minimum cost flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem).

Recall how we make a network for a standard bipartite matching.

1. For each vertex *u* from *L*, add a unit-capacity edge from *S* to *u*;
2. For each edge *u-v*, where *u* is from *L* and *v* is from *R*, add an edge from *u* to *v*. Note that its capacity does not matter as long as it is at least one;
3. For each vertex *v* from *R*, add a unit-capacity edge from *u* to *R*.

Now we keep the central part the same and change left and right parts a bit.

1. For each vertex *u* from *L*, add **two** unit-capacity edges from *S* to *u*, one of them of having cost -1 and another having cost 0;

Same for edges *v->S*.

Ignoring cost, this is the same network you built yourself. The maximum flow here corresponds to the maximum double-matching.

Now let's find the minimum cost flow of size *k*. It corresponds to some double-matching, and of those it corresponds to the matching that touches the maximum possible number of vertices, because touching a vertex (that is, pushing at least unit flow through it) decreases the cost by 1. Moreover, touching the vertex for the second time doesn't decrease the cost because the second edge has cost 0.

How we have the solution: for each *k = 1, ..., 2n* iteratively find the min-cost flow and take the value which corresponds to the minimum cost.

Using [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) (also called Dijkstra's with potentials) gives O(n^2) per iteration, which is O(n^3) overall.

P.S. The runtime of Dinic's algorithm on unit graphs is better, reaching O(E sqrt(V)) on bipartite graphs.